# Can I ignore specific migrations when running Laravel unit tests

Tags: php, laravel

When running tests in Laravel (php artisan test), I get an error 'duplicate column name: created_at'. This only occurs when i have field additions in the migrations directory. Am i able to ignore specific files when running Laravel tests? Or is there another way to get round this issue?

migrations:
if i just have this table, the tests work fine:

```
2021_06_18_134444_create_users_tables.php
```

after creating this migration, the tests fail:

```
2021_07_08_135544_add_timestamps_to_all_tables.php
```

a simple test:

```
use RefreshDatabase;
public function test_redirect_to_home_page_after_login()
    {                

        $user = User::factory()->make([
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'test@hotmail.com', 
            'password' => bcrypt('123456')
        ]);      

        $response = $this->post('login', [
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'test@hotmail.com',
            'password' => '123456'          
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect('/');
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors();
    }
```

Comment: Does `create_users_tables` already add that column? Do the migrations run when you `php artisan migrate:fresh` (will remove all data, caution)?

Comment: well created_at does exist within the create_users_table migration, however, the users table doesnt actually feature in add_timestamps_to_all_tables. if i remove instances of 'created_at from the add migration i get error: Cannot add a column with non-constant default

Comment: Maybe you can add a check in your `2021_07_08_135544_add_timestamps_to_all_tables` migration like `Schema::hasColumn('TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME')`, and then add the column if that returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `up()` & `down()` functions with such condition.

```php
if (app()->runningUnitTests()) {
   // your function content
}
```